# Cost Path based on Lowest Maximum Elevation Encountered

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, hydrology, cost-path

I am trying to locate the lowest elevation point at which a river will overtop its banks, and spill into lower-lying terrain behind them. I'm working in ArcMap version 10.2, and using a high-resolution DEM to represent the surface.

My thought was that I could approach this as a kind of cost-path problem, where the path would only be concerned with finding the smallest maximum elevation along a route between the river and low-lying terrain (like trying to find the lowest pass through a mountain range).

Is it possible to create a least-cost path that only accounts for the maximum value encountered? And if not, are there any other tools I could use to locate the spill point?

Comment: Can be multiple points along the river? Which one are you after?

Comment: I understood your thought but was wondering, how do you want to encounter the slope of the river in this equation. The lowest point of overflow will always be down stream if you only look at altitude values.

Comment: FelixIP - I'm not sure I understand your comment. There could be multiple spill points along the river, but I'm interested in the lowest elevation spill point.  
@EikeMike - Good point. In my case, the slope of the river is negligible for the length I'm looking at, so I'm simplifying by ignoring the gradient. But this wouldn't work for a steeper river or larger reach.

Answer (score 1):

Understanding your idea, I do not see any possibility to use the cost distance tool on the base of “Lowest Maximum Elevation Encountered”. The function adds costs multiplied by distance. It would be necessary to transform the cost (altitude) values in a way that any rise in cost is higher than the sum of whole cost path. I guess this is possible for a few integer cost values but not for a float altitude value. As you have the possibility to work with the Spatial Analyst, did you think about using the [Hydrology Toolset](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/deriving-runoff-characteristics.htm). You would need to convert your riverbed to a sink to use this Toolset for your purpose.